# Show that $u$ is constant for some positive function $u$ on $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

> Suppose $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0$ for some positive function $u$ on $\Bbb R^2$. Show that $u$ is constant.

I am not sure how to show this but I think this has something to do with the Cauchy Riemann Equations. Since $u_x = v_y$ we have $$u_{xx} = v_{yx}$$

Likewise, $u_y = −v_x$ implies $$u_{yy} = −v_{xy}$$
Since $v_{xy} = v_{yx}$, we have $$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = v_{yx} −v_{xy} = 0$$.
Thus $u$ is harmonic. But I do not know how to show $u$ is constant. This just shows $u$ is harmonic. What are the steps do I have to follow to show what is required? Do I have to assume a holomorphic function $f$ such that $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y) $ and then work my way?

Comment: Yes, use $f$; note that $\frac 1 {f+1}$ is a bounded entire function.

Comment: "Since $u_x = v_y$"... huh? Where did $v$ come from?

Comment: @5xum That is from the Cauchy Riemann Equation. I just assumed that this follows from the Cauchy Riemann Equation. I do not know how to show it.

Comment: @esquire But what is $v$?

Comment: If I assume a holomorphic function $f$ such that $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y) $. Then I have a $v$ @5xum

Comment: @esquire Why can you assume that?